# Finding boundary of line integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

...with the conditions of $C$ being the intersection of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9$ and $x^2+y^2 = 1$ with $y \geq 0$.

The integral in question is here: $ \int_C\,dl $

Thing is I'm really confused. I asked my friend and he said this was a case of triple integral stuff instead.

Or is this the curve I'm supposed to find?

[image]

If it is, then how should I go with setting every other variables as $t$? I'm sorry if I come off as being stupid but I'm really new with line integral stuff.

Comment: I can set x as = cost and y = sint but I'm stuck on z

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you Jose!

Comment: $~x^2 + y^2 = 1~$ and $~x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9~$ collectively imply that $~z^2 = 8.$  So, $~z~$ must equal $~\pm \displaystyle 2\sqrt{2}~$ and $~(x,y)~$ must represent half of the unit circle, since $~y~$ must be $~\geq 0.$

Comment: So it should be something like this?
$x = cost$;
$y = sint$;
$z = \pm 2 \sqrt{2}$
with $t \in [0, π]$
and with that we have $\int_0^π \sqrt{sin(t)^2 + cos(t)^2 + 0} \, dt = π$ for both z cases?

Comment: Do I have to combine both z cases to get the actual integral? In this case it should be $2π$